# UnityでAdmobを画面下に設置するとAndrdoidアプリの場合のみ下に余白が出来てしまう。

Tags: android, unity3d, admob

初めてUnityでゲームを作ったのですが、Admobを画面下部に設置(AdPosition.Bottom)したところ、ぴったりと画面下部には付かず、アクションバー分くらいの余白が出来てしまいます。
iPhoneの場合はぴったり画面下に表示されます。

AdPosition.Topへ上部に設置した場合は余白が出来ずにぴったりと表示されます。

検索で探したのですが、同一の現象で困っている方も見当たらず、原因が分からずに困っています。

どなたか解決方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

unityでandroidライブラリを読んでいるですがそのライブラリでは
PopupWindowでバナーを表示しています。
ですのでこのPopupWindowに条件付けすれば消えると思いますよ。

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/blob/master/source/android-library/app/src/main/java/com/google/unity/ads/Banner.java
の205行目に

```
mPopupWindow.getContentView().setSystemUiVisibility(android.view.View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY|android.view.View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN|android.view.View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

を追加してandroidプロジェクトをunityで動くライブラリに変化して元のファイルと置換えすれば消えると思います。
実際に動かしていないので間違っていたらすみません。（その際は訂正します